# How to use ClearCanvas.Server.ShredHost

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clearcanvas

How can i use `ClearCanvas.Server.ShredHost` to get all images on my servers?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you want to do?  It is difficult to discern what you actually want to do.  Do you want to do a DICOM query/retrieve to get a study from another server?  You need to edit and clarify the question.